# How to show driving direction between My location to Destination

Tags: android, google-maps

Here i am trying to use the below code snippet to show driving direction or route on map

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Then what's the error or issue?

Comment: I want to pass my current location also How can i pass

Comment: If you are using map intent passing to google map, Google map will automatically take your current location. you don't need to pass at all. You have to specify source and destination

Comment: Can i pass String to saddr and daddr

Comment: The one which you already passed in URI is right. No need to do anything now. when it will open in google map, map will show your current location by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start the navigation from the current location, remove the saddr parameter and value.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks . Can u tell how to show crime reports around the fixed location. What i should i have to do.